# Did a recent Windows Update significantly reduce usable RAM on low-end devices?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, netbook, internet-explorer-11, out-of-memory

I've been running Windows 7 Starter on a HP netbook with the maximum amount of RAM Microsoft allowed netbook manufacturers to have and still be eligible to ship with OEM Windows (2 gigabytes).

This has worked fine for me over the last couple of years. I do light programming, edit photos, and often had up to a hundred tabs open.

But one or two months ago there was a Windows Update, the one which brought Internet Explorer 11.

Since that time I am now plagues with two new warning dialogs I don't recall seeing before: that I am running low on memory and should close certain recommended apps.

If I do persist without closing enough apps or tabs I now often have the browser or another app close down. This used to be very rare indeed and is now painfully common. I don't even use IE11, but Google Chrome.

Could this be due to IE11 pre-loading more stuff into memory than previous versions even when I'm not using it? Or is it a known problem others are suffering under Windows 7 on low-end machines?

Comment: It could be that something played with your desktop heap size, check [this fix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947246) from MS it could solve your problem.

Comment: You don't mention what version of IE you were using before.

Comment: @Ramhound: It would've been whatever previous Windows Updates had got it to. I assume some revisious of IE10, but if there's a way I can check I can let you know.

Comment: I must aplogize, I skipped over the fact, you don't even use IE.  IE11 simply being installed would not effect your system performance.

Comment: @Ramhound: Well it shouldn't except that I recall that back during the browser wars MS made it a compusory part of the system saying it can't be removed... and made some amount of it autoload to boost its apparent startup time. But it could also be something else altered by the same Windows Update, or a different update right around the same time.

Comment: provide the data from RAMMap when you get the issue again: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/08/13/introduction-to-the-new-sysinternals-tool-rammap.aspx

Comment: @HaLaBi: I've run the MS fix and for the last few hours things *seem* much better. I'll keep monitoring the situation before deciding whether it's really fixed.

Comment: Indeed everything looked great from the time I installed the MS fix until today, ten days later. Now even running just Google Chrome with a single tab results in constant browser/tab crashing. I've disabled extensions to rule those out ...

Comment: After freeing up some disk space things seem to be going OK again for now ...